# How to add href link to bootstrap rollover image?

Tags: href

Warning: I'm a noob.  The little I know comes from fiddling around.

I maintain a hobby website of images created in bootstrap 3 and I would like to have a responsive rollover image that also links to the full size image.

I have been able to complete the responsive rollover part, but I can't figure out how to add the link to display the full image.

Here's what I have so far:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/11cmcznn/
```

HTML:

```
<div class="rollover-wrapper-1"><div class="rollover-image-1"></div>
```

I can't post the CSS because I don't have reputation points yet.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put href before the div and make sure you close the parent div too. Like this

```
<div class="rollover-wrapper-1"><a href="http://google.com"><div class="rollover-image-1"></div></a></div>
```

Comment: THANKS!  I think I forgot to close the div when I tried earlier.  That did it!

Answer (score 0):

Well I've run into another problem.  I have the rollover image working properly including linking to the full size image.  But for some reason whenever I add the code to the webpage and the style sheet, somehow the webpage is looking for the style sheet in the wrong place on my website.

I have a style sheet "default.css" that I use for all my webpages.  This css sheet is in the root of the website.  But for some reason the webpage with the rollover image will not display the image, and when I inspect the element within Chrome it gives me 404 error stating that the default.css is not found in a certain folder on the website.  I've never had the default.css in any folder besides the root.

So somehow the webpage is looking for a style sheet in a place where none exists, and I have no idea why.

If I copy the default.css style sheet from the root into the folder it's looking for then the webpage loads properly, but I don't want to have to maintain two identical style sheets.  I just don't know how the style sheet got attached to the webpage.

I'm sorry for the vagueness of this problem, but I don't know enough to make a more informed question.